# Is it possible to create multiple images of different size given in json file from one single image using objective c or swift

Tags: objective-c, json, swift

Is it possible to create multiple images of different size given in json file     from one single image using objective c or swift?

Please anyone can help me out,as I am new to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(reSize.width, reSize.height));
 [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, reSize.width, reSize.height)];
 UIImage *reSizeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but with this is it possible to create multiple images with different sizes given in json file?
can you please share any demo example.

Comment: your question is too generic. You have to publish your code to get a more precise answer.